# web.py : Error loading multiple html files via iFrames

Tags: python, html, iframe, web.py

I am learning `web.py` and trying out a application where `web.py` needs to load a `html` file having `iframes` that loads three different `html` files.

The `index.html` file loads properly with desired results when launched directly from  `web-browser`, However gives `not found` error upon loading via `app.py`.

Here is directory structure:

```
appdir/  
      app.py  
      templates/  
               index.html
               frames_top.html
               frames_left.html
               frames_right.html
```

**Here are contents of `index.html`**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example - Frames</title>
</head>
<iframe name="top_frame" src="frames_top.html" width="100%" height="100"> scrolling="no" align="top" </iframe> 

<iframe name="left_frame" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 10px; height:1222px; width:10%;" src="frames_left.html" target="right_frame" scrolling="no" align="left" >
</iframe>

<iframe name="right_frame" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 10px; height:1222px; width:90%;" src="frames_right.html" target="right_frame" scrolling="no" align="middle" >
</iframe> 
</html>
```

and here are contents of `app.py`

```
import web

""" url definition""" 
urls = (
  '^/$', 'do_index_frame',
  '^/$', 'do_left_frame',
  '^/$', 'do_right_frame',
  '^/$', 'do_top_frame'
)


app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/')

class do_index_frame:
    def GET(self):
        return render.index()

class do_left_frame:    
    def GET(self):
        return render.frames_left()

class do_right_frame:    
    def GET(self):
        return render.frames_right()

class do_top_frame:    
    def GET(self):   
        return render.frames_top()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When I run `app.py` and launch browser at `127.0.0.1:8080`,
**I get following screen**

[image]

**With this error:**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
http://0.0.0.0:8080/
127.0.0.1:56483 - - [25/May/2016 15:00:06] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 200 OK
127.0.0.1:56483 - - [25/May/2016 15:00:07] "HTTP/1.1 GET /frames_top.html" - 404 Not Found127.0.0.1:56482 - - [25/May/2016 15:00:07] "HTTP/1.1 GET /frames_left.html" - 404 Not Found

127.0.0.1:56493 - - [25/May/2016 15:00:07] "HTTP/1.1 GET /frames_right.html" - 404 Not Found
127.0.0.1:58680 - - [25/May/2016 15:13:25] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 200 OK
127.0.0.1:58680 - - [25/May/2016 15:13:25] "HTTP/1.1 GET /frames_top.html" - 404 Not Found
127.0.0.1:58682 - - [25/May/2016 15:13:25] "HTTP/1.1 GET /frames_left.html" - 404 Not Found
 127.0.0.1:58681 - - [25/May/2016 15:13:25] "HTTP/1.1 GET /frames_right.html" - 404 Not Found
```

Is anyone able to determine the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through `web.py` documentation, all I needed to do was to provide file name with full path of `html` files in order to make them accessible via `urls`.

I thought I would post here in case anyone else runs into similar issue.

```
""" url definition""" 
urls = (
  '/path/to/files/index.html', 'do_index_frame',
  '/path/to/files/left.html', 'do_left_frame',
  '/path/to/files/right.html', 'do_right_frame',
  '/path/to/files/top.html', 'do_top_frame'
)
```